# Part numbers for rear drive mounts for R730xd?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I bought a refurbished R730xd without the rear 2.5" drives, and am now investigating how to add drives. The system does not appear to have come with the necessary mounting hardware to actually put drives in the two rear mounting locations (right now, they're really just empty spaces), so it appears I have to find mounting brackets to hold disk trays and also any associated cabling and maybe circuit boards that may be necessary. Googling around, I have not been able to identify what the part numbers might be. Can anyone point me in the right direction? What are the necessary parts to make the rear drives work? And also, where do they connect or plug into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, but call Dell is your only option.

I have access to open waranty call, and even from their system we have no piece number, we need to give the servicetag and describe the faulty piece and they ship after.

When like you we need special piece for out of warranty order we need to contact our dell representative.

*If you live in canada you can contact me by email to have the info with a price, if you dont want to call.*

Answer (score 0):

A Dell representative responded to me and said there are no upgrade kits for the R730xd. According to them, *"Due to differences between the multiple chassis models offered with the R720XD, the chassis option must be selected at the point of purchase and cannot be changed or upgraded at a later time."*

While this is not a direct answer to my original question (I still don't know the part numbers), it addresses the root question, which is how to add rear drives to an R730xd that did not come with them. The answer appears to be: there is no way.

Comment: I just hope the rep correctly understood you, as they can see the original's spec, thus it's not an upgrade you want to do, you just want it working as I see it in your question

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thank you for your thoughtfulness. As it turns out, I did not actually contact Dell directly; I made a separate query to a mailing list, and the person replying could not have known the specs of the machine (unless they have truly mysterious powers). However, you're right that it _is_ possible they had in mind a "proper" upgrade, and not (say) buying parts on eBay. Nevertheless, their answer implies that the necessary parts are not generally sold separately.

Comment: Yeah, dell is hard to get part separately :( This is where I like less dell. (unlike hp that you can have all piece for 10 years, or ibm)